# Isn't these two code snippets for SQL SERVER return same value

Tags: sql-server

In my sql server I got a table named "Product" where a column named "P_name" exist. This column is completely null meaning it has null value in all of its rows eg:

| P_name |
| --- |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |

I wrote two queries. My first query is:

```
declare @value int
select value = count(P_name) from Product
```

It returned the value of 0 (which is correct because the P_name column is completely null)

I wrote the second query as follows:

```
declare @colName nvarchar(max) = 'P_name';
declare @value int
select value = count(@colName) from Product
```

This returned a value with 3 (which I suppose is wrong)

Isn't both query snippets are same and suppose to return the same value in my case 0? Why they are producing two different values?

Answer (score 2):

In the second query, you are not counting a column, but a static value for each row in the Products table, you actually are running:

```
SELECT COUNT('P_Name') FROM DBO.Product
```

instead of giving the column name in the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(P_Name) FROM DBO.Product
```

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Use the first query or dynamic sql if you want to use dynamic columns